# button onclick this.form.submit call validate function

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I want to call validate function on form submit. When i write following code.

```
<form onSubmit = 'return validate();'>
<input type='url'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Work fine. But if i have input type button. And I write following code.

```
<form onSubmit = 'return validate();'>
<input type='url'>
<input type='button' onclick = this.form.submit(); value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Not working.

Comment: use type as submit. not as button

Answer (score 6):

Put  `this.form.submit();` in quotes,

```
 <form onSubmit = 'return validate();'>
    <input type='url'>
    <input type='button' onclick = 'this.form.submit();' value='Submit'>
    </form>
```

its worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="url">
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submitBtn").click(function(e)({
   $("#myForm").submit();
 )};
)};
```

Comment: Where is you call validate function ?

Comment: you want to submit the form or to call validate function before form submission?

Comment: $(document).ready(function()(
 $("#submitBtn").click(function(e)({
   if(validate())
   {
    $("#myForm").submit();
   }
 )};
)};

Comment: I want validate form before submit

Comment: The is a { missing at the end of the first line..
Should be $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: @AlbuquerqueWebDesign, Thanks. Have corrected the code

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submitBtn").click(function(e)({
   if(validate())
   {
     $("#myForm").submit();
   }
 )};
)};
```

The validate function should return true on successful execution only then the form will get submit.

Comment: Following error is showing
ReferenceError: validate is not defined
if(validate()) {

Comment: is there a function named validate()?

Comment: function()( is bad .. it is supossed to be function(){
function(e)({ is bad .. it is supossed to befunction(e){

Answer (score 0):

all function declarations start with a {

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#submitBtn").click(function(e){
       $("#myForm").submit();
     });
    });
```